# Spring Batch with Throttle limit and Skip limit

Tags: spring-batch

I have Multi-threaded Step with a throttle limit as 10(assume) and the skip limit for the job is been configured as 5. My input file which has 20 records, have more than 10 invalid records in it. In this case whenever my job fails, it doesn't fail when it reaches 5 negative cases. It stops somewhere around 12 or 13th failure.

Comment: Can you please provide a MCV (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code example to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I don't quite understand what your question is